# Fine grained access control with Spring Boot managed custom permissions and Keycloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I'm working on a Spring Boot / Spring Security application which uses Keycloak as Identity and Access Management (IAM) component. We have a user interface where admin can define the sub users and relevant permissions to view, edit, and delete different modules. These permissions can be updated time to time and currently maintained in our application's Postgres database.

I have done the initial implementation with Spring Security generated JWT token where I added these permissions as Granted Authorities and used the annotations such as `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('LIST_CURRENCIES')")` at method level to achieve this. But when I offloaded the IAM to Keycloak so far it has not been successful to enforce method level security.

How could we sync these permissions to Keycloak so that list of permissions for each user can be included in the JWT token as claims that can be enforced by Spring Security?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the `api` module of https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies.

In this project, I define a custom mapper for keycloak to add a custom claim to access tokens and then use it in spring-security SpEL.